# C# String.Format bug?

Tags: c#, windows-10, string.format

I am having trouble understanding why this code produces the results it does:

```
$ type t.cs

using System;
using static System.Console;
using static System.Environment;

class P
{
  public static void Main()
  { uint a=1;
    string b="a string";
    string c=String.Format ( $"{0}\t{1}" , a , b) ;
    Out.WriteLine( c );
    Exit(0);
  }
}

$ csc t.cs 
Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 2.9.0.63208 (958f2354)
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
$ .\T.EXE
0       1
```

I have read the documentation on String.Format at:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=net-5.0
but I still am none the wiser as to how to explain why the above code prints
"0<tab>1" instead of "1<tab>a string" .

Please could anyone enlighten me?

Comment: you are mixing string interpolation with string formatting. use just one of them. string.Format receives string that does not have any placeholders to replace as interpolation takes place first

Comment: Which means you need to remove the `$` in front of the formatting string.

Answer (score 3):

This [interpolated string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) literal expression:

```
$"{0}\t{1}"
```

Will evaluate to:

```
"0\t1"
```

... before being passed to `string.Format()` - and since it has no placeholders, the input arguments are ignored and the resulting string is just `"0\t1"`.

Change to:

```
string c = String.Format("{0}\t{1}", a, b); // no interpolation of template string
```

or

```
string c = $"{a}\t{b}"; // expand a and b inline using interpolation
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using string interpolation -> $"{}"; {0} and {1} aren't placeholders in this case, they are literals. Remove dollar sign before string "{0}\t{1}" and you'll get what you expect.

Comment: Aha ! Thank You to all who answered above!